# Esp32 to node-red get request

Tags: get, httpclient, iot, esp32, node-red

Hello i am trying to make get request from esp32 to node red, I have managed to make a successful request but I am only receiving empty:

[image]

this my simple nodered Flow

[image]
And this my Esp32 code :

`

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>

// This example downloads the URL "http://arduino.cc/"
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
// Timer set to 10 minutes (600000)
// unsigned long timerDelay = 600000;
// Set timer to 5 seconds (5000)
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;
// Name of the server we want to connect to
const char kHostname[] = "3.145.1.222";
// Path to download (this is the bit after the hostname in the URL
// that you want to download
const char kPath[] = "/data";

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

// Number of milliseconds to wait without receiving any data before we give up
const int kNetworkTimeout = 30 * 1000;
// Number of milliseconds to wait if no data is available before trying again
const int kNetworkDelay = 1000;
void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.init(5);
  while (Ethernet.begin(mac) != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Error getting IP address via DHCP, trying again...");
    delay(15000);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Hello wo");
  int err = 0;
  EthernetClient client;
  HttpClient http(client);
  err = http.get(kHostname,
                 1880,
                 kPath,
                 NULL);
  if (err == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("startedRequest ok");
  }
  String temperature = "44";
  String requestBody = "{\"temperature\":\"" + temperature + "\"}";
  int contentLength = requestBody.length();
  char contentLenght[] = "21";
  char c[] = "{\"temperature\":\"44\"}";
  http.sendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.sendHeader("Content-Length", String(contentLength).c_str());
  http.sendHeader("");
  http.print(requestBody);
  Serial.println(http.responseStatusCode());
  delay(10000);
}
```

`

I have tried using multiple libraries and this is the only one made a successful get rquest but unfortunatlly empty

Comment: HTTP get requests should not have a body...

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the HTTP GET request for a POST as GET requests are not meant to have a body.

You will also need to update the Node-RED flow's HTTP-in node to expect a POST to match.

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Hello wo");
  int err = 0;
  EthernetClient client;
  HttpClient http(client);
  err = http.post(kHostname,
                 1880,
                 kPath,
                 NULL);
  if (err == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("startedRequest ok");
  }
  String temperature = "44";
  String requestBody = "{\"temperature\":\"" + temperature + "\"}";
  int contentLength = requestBody.length();
  char contentLenght[] = "21";
  char c[] = "{\"temperature\":\"44\"}";
  http.sendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.sendHeader("Content-Length", String(contentLength).c_str());
  http.sendHeader("");
  http.print(requestBody);
  Serial.println(http.responseStatusCode());
  delay(10000);
}
```